# Update value in array of objects inside JSON field

Tags: mysql, json

I have a column in my database with a JSON like this one:

```
{
"customer": "Jay",
"items": [
{"id": "232143b123", "name": "Laptop", "shipping": "to be shipped" },
{"id": "1232bsadse", "name": "Monitor", "shipping": "to be shipped"},
{"id": "3123hsadhesz", "name": "Monitor", "shipping": "to be shipped"}
]
}
```

I need a query to update the shipping status and I have the 'id' to search.

I tried to use JSON_SEARCH but maybe I misunderstood the function and I couldn't make it work

How can I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you use JSON to store these data, given that you don't know how to update it, and it would totally easy to update if you stored the data in normal rows and columns?

Comment: @BillKarwin I just gave an example, the real JSON has over 100 properties and I'm just doing some maintenance, I'm not the author